# "cannot execute binary file" on Cygwin

Tags: gcc, fortran, cygwin

*Preface: Using cygwin on a Win7 machine.*

I have some old (very old) f77 code (45,000 lines in 25 files) written by someone else that I am trying to use.

Yesterday I compiled, linked and ran it OK (using f77 compiler). I then made some mods (increasing array sizes) and kept getting segmentation faults when executing. Wondering if there was a compatibility problem I then fiddled with the settings in Windows (to no avail).

Now I cannot even run the compiled program - I get a "cannot execute binary file" error. I cannot even compile and run the original version of the code.

There were only some minor warnings during the compiling and none during the linking.

I have:

- Checked permissions (all OK:- user::rwx)
- Checked via *file* and get: "PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows".
- Written a test program to check my compiler commands and it ran as expected.
- Copied all source code to another directory to see if that was problem (it didn't help).
- Tried to run the executable from a windows command prompt and get "not a valid Win32 application" (and yet a previous executable executes OK).

What may have happened between yesterday and today that is stopping this program executing.  Is it related to my fiddling with the compatibility settings?  Or is it something in the code that lets it compile and link OK but not execute?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: "Fiddled with the settings in Windows". If you don't know what you have changed, you can try to restore from a checkpoint. Otherwise there's little hope.

Comment: I simply changed the compatibility options for that file ("run this program in compatibility mode for ...") - nothing to do with Windows operating system.

Comment: Change it back to what it was. Doesn't work? You have unknowingly changed something else.

Comment: The executable has been deleted and recreated. When I check the new one now it has the default compatibility options as it had originally. Besides, the problem exists in a new directory with a new file. Maybe the compatibility fiddling is a red herring.

Comment: Can you compile and run *any* program? "Hello world"?

Comment: As I said - I have written a test program to check my compiler commands and it ran as expected.

Comment: What exact commands are you using?

Comment: All the files are in the one directory so simply:-
To compile:    f77 -Wall -ffixed-line-length-132 -I. -c *.F
To link:      f77 -Wall *.o -o freddo.exe

Comment: Try `cygcheck freddo.exe` and `ldd freddo.exe`

Comment: `cygcheck freddo.exe
C:\cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-RtlSupport-L1-1-0.dll
      C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
      C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll`
and lots more: API-MS-Win-.....

Comment: ldd freddo.exe 

Exec format error

Comment: [Nobody seems to know why this happens](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-11/threads.html#00024). Look at the bottom thread. You may want to try rebooting and/or completely wiping reinstall cygwin. I don't know if it will help.